# How to calculate AVERAGE(POWER(A1:A2, 10)) in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I can do this creating a new column `B` where `=POWER(A1, 10)` and then I get the result with `=AVERAGE(B1:B2)`. But how to do that without a new column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [an array formula](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArrayFormulas.aspx) to do this.  Let's say your numbers to set to a power are in cells `A1` to `A9`, you can find what you want by entering the following formula into a cell:

```
=AVERAGE(POWER(A1:A9, 10))
```

When you are done entering the formula, you need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter it as an array formula.

Comment: The only problem is that empty lines aren't ignored